# django rest api json data category subcategory

Tags: json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to access subcategories according to parent id. When i am checking subcategories api it's showing all data with all parent id. I am unable to filter subcategories according to parent id. I am trying to get json data according to parent id.

If our parent id is 7 so i need all subcategories which one's has parent id 7. Please guide how i can do its.

***models.py***

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)

    
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    id_parent = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

***json***

```
[
 {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "IT Servic",
     "price": 2000,
     "status": true,
     "id_parent": 7
 },
 {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Web Development",
     "price": 1000,
     "status": true,
     "id_parent": 8
 },
 {
     "id": 3,
     "name": "Digital Marketing",
     "price": 3000,
     "status": true,
     "id_parent": 7
 },
 {
     "id": 4,
     "name": "RO Repair",
     "price": 3444,
     "status": true,
     "id_parent": 9
 }
]
```

***serializers.py***

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'


class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubCategory
        fields = '__all__'
    lookup_field = 'id_parent'
```

**views.py***

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active and user.is_superuser:
                    return Category.objects.all()
                raise PermissionDenied()
            raise PermissionDenied()                    
        raise PermissionDenied()


class SubCategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active and user.is_superuser:
                    return SubCategory.objects.all()
                raise PermissionDenied()
            raise PermissionDenied()
        raise PermissionDenied()
   

    serializer_class = SubCategorySerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/).

Basically, you can either do your filtering "manually" in the `get_queryset()`

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    id_parent = self.request.query_params.get('id_parent')
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    if id_parent:
        queryset = queryset.filter(id_parent=id_parent)
    return queryset
```

Or use a third-party library such as [`django-filter`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a custom action to your `viewset` like this, assuming you can set the appropriate urls/routes

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
def get_sub_categories(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    category_id = self.request.query_params.get("category_id", None)
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    filtered_sub_categories = queryset.filter(id_parent=category_id)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(filtered_sub_categories, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```